# Microservices : not getting response but all services are running

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I am new into microservices, my all services are up but i do not get response from API. Could you please help me to find out exact cause? how to handle it?

Comment: Please provide some more detail. How it is deploy and how you are calling it ?

Comment: micro-services with spring boot and mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at logs for any kind of exception/error, also check mongod shell. You might not have data in mongodb for given criteria if you don't see any error/exception in logs.